# Use calculated fields to calculate new field in $project with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a collection `Item` with fields `_id`, `price`, and `project` as well as a collection `Project` with fields `_id` and `name`.

The items have different prices, so I want to group the items by `price` and count how many items are in each group and save the value as `quantity`.

Then I want to compute `quantity` and `price` to get the total amount. But I want to calculate some fees. The fees should be computed as `totalPrice * (1 + 10/100) + 5 * quantity`.

So I have tried using `$project` to calculate each fee and it works, but I cannot create a final calculated field with the total price including the fees. I think I am not able to use a calculated field in the same `$project`?

I have used the following code, but `totalPriceWithFees` becomes 0:

```
Item.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        project: '$project',
        price: '$price'
      },
      quantity: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      quantity: 1,
      totalPriceWithoutFees: {
        $multiply: ['$_id.price', '$quantity']
      },
      feesPercentage: {
        $multiply: ['$_id.price', 0.1]
      },
      feesAbsolute: {
        $multiply: ['$quantity', 5]
      },
      fees: {
        $sum: ['feesPercentage', 'feesAbsolute']
      },
      totalPriceWithFees: {
        $sum: ['$totalPriceWithoutFees', '$fees']
      },
    }
  }
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Project',
      localField: '_id.project',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'project'
    }
  }
])
```

Also, I want to populate the project. I have only saved the project id, so I need to populate to get the project name. I am not sure if it's possible with normal `populate()` in Mongoose, so I have tried using `$lookup`, but it also doesn't work. The field `project` just becomes empty.